# How do I clean build and installs, ie un-build?

Tags: apt, uninstall, build, cleanup

I have installed and downloaded and built mongodb, and just one works.

`$ mongo`

```
mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libmozjs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`$ /opt/mongo/bin/mongo`

```
/opt/mongo/bin/mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system-mt.so.1.38.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`$ /usr/bin/mongo`

```
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5
connecting to: test
>
```

I can remove the installation via apt-get. But how do I remove all things mongo that were built with make, and get a clean system? I followed this [guide](http://sethbc.org/2010/04/04/building-and-installing-mongodb-on-ubuntu-10-04/) to build and install mongodb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source, create a .deb package corresponding to the manual install procedure using checkinstall:

```
sudo checkinstall make install
```

Once the package is created and installed you can remove it:

```
sudo dpkg -r package_name
```

Usually it's better to use checkinstall during initial installation, as it allows you to easily rollback the install.

Comment: well, that doesnt answer my question of how to remove my current executable, but maybe if I manually do a `which mongo` and remove that, it should work. Ill remember to do a checkinstall next time on.

Comment: yes you rebuild/install the package as explained it will overwrite your current binary, dpkg -r will then remove not only the executable but all files related to it. You can manually remove the mongo binary, however that will not remove other files that may have been installed and which are no longer required.